# Keeping a MouseListener always running

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I have this constructor:

```
public Board(final boolean[][] board) {
    this.board = board;
    height = board.length;
    width = board[0].length;
    setBackground(Color.black);
    button1 = new JButton("Run");
    add(button1);
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            isActive = !isActive;
            button1.setText(isActive ? "Pause" : "Run");
        }
    });
    button2 = new JButton("Random");
    add(button2);
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setBoard(randomBoard());
        }
    });
    button3 = new JButton("Clear");
    add(button3);
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setBoard(clearBoard());
        }
    });
    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {         
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            board[e.getY() / multiplier][e.getX() / multiplier] = !board[e.getY() / multiplier][e.getX() / multiplier];
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {       
        }
    });
}
```

The `ActionListener`s are always 'listening'; however the `MouseListener`stops 'listening' after I click Run (`button1`). Why is this and how do I make `MouseListener` remain listening?

If it's any use, I also have this `paintComponent` class:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            g.setColor(board[i][j] ? Color.green : Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(j * multiplier, i * multiplier, multiplier - 1, multiplier - 1);
        }
    }
    if (isActive) {
        timer.start();
    }
    else {
        timer.stop();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider variable names like `btnRun`, `btnClear`, and `btnRandom` instead of `button1`, `button2`, and `button3`.

Comment: @whiskeyspider `Timer timer = new Timer(500, this);`

Comment: @Lewis What is the timer task doing?  Starting timers and calling `repaint()` from `paintComponent()` is probably your problem.

Comment: `paintComponent` is only meant for painting a component (ie, change the color of its pixels using the `Graphics` methods). You cannot rely on when and how many times it will be called. The OS will trigger repaints as well as your code. This is pretty random. So starting and stopping Timers in it, is a very bad practice and will very likely be the cause of issues.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

A `MouseListener` will continue to work as long as the object you added it to is still alive and assuming you haven't called `removeMouseListener()` on it.  As your program runs and changes data and such, the behavior of the code inside your listener may change (e.g., a flag is set causing it to ignore a call to another method), but the listener will be "always running" and its methods *will* be called.

(As I mentioned in my comment, your problem likely has to do with the strange things you are doing in your `paintComponent()` method.)