# Game Of Life Java MouseAdapter doesn't always work

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

Sometimes the `mousePressed` event gets executed , but at other times it won't. It also seems to depend on the time you press it. How do I get it to ALWAYS work?

I'm not sure which part of the code is faulty, so here's the whole class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, this);

    private boolean[][] board;
    private boolean isActive = false;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int multiplier = 20;

    private JButton btnRun;
    private JButton btnRand;
    private JButton btnClear;

    public Board() {
        this(new boolean[20][20]);
    }

    public Board(final boolean[][] board) {
        this.board = board;
        height = board.length;
        width = board[0].length;
        setBackground(Color.black);
        btnRun = new JButton("Run");
        add(btnRun);
        btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isActive = !isActive;
                btnRun.setText(isActive ? "Pause" : "Run");
            }
        });
        btnRand = new JButton("Random");
        add(btnRand);
        btnRand.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setBoard(randomBoard());
            }
        });
        btnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        add(btnClear);
        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setBoard(clearBoard());
            }
        });
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                getBoard()[e.getY() / multiplier][e.getX() / multiplier] = !getBoard()[e.getY() / multiplier][e.getX() / multiplier];
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public int getMultiplier() {
        return multiplier;
    }

    public boolean[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(boolean[][] boardToSet) {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                board[i][j] = boardToSet[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                g.setColor(board[i][j] ? Color.green : Color.gray);
                g.fillRect(j * multiplier, i * multiplier, multiplier - 1, multiplier - 1);
            }
        }
        if (isActive) {
            timer.start();
        }
        else {
            timer.stop();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        board = nextGeneration();
        repaint();
    }

    public boolean[][] randomBoard() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        boolean[][] randBoard = new boolean[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                randBoard[i][j] = rand.nextBoolean();
            }
        }
        return randBoard;
    }

    public boolean[][] clearBoard() {
        boolean[][] emptyBoard = new boolean[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                emptyBoard[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        return emptyBoard;
    }

    public int countSurrounding(int a, int b) {
        int count = 0;
        int[][] surrounding = {{a - 1, b - 1},
                               {a - 1, b    },
                               {a - 1, b + 1},
                               {a    , b - 1},
                               {a    , b + 1},
                               {a + 1, b - 1},
                               {a + 1, b    },
                               {a + 1, b + 1}};
        for (int[] i: surrounding) {
            try {
                if (board[i[0]][i[1]]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
        }
        return count;
    }

    public boolean[][] nextGeneration() {
        boolean[][] nextBoard = new boolean[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                nextBoard[i][j] = board[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] && !(countSurrounding(i, j) == 2 || countSurrounding(i, j) == 3)) {
                    nextBoard[i][j] = false;
                }
                else if (!board[i][j] && countSurrounding(i, j) == 3) {
                    nextBoard[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return nextBoard;
    }   
}
```

Comment: No need to paste the code twice..

Comment: Could be the rounding in `getBoard()[e.getY() / multiplier][e.getX() / multiplier]`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552392/keeping-a-mouselistener-always-running/16552941#16552941

Comment: @whiskeyspider it's a slightly different problem

Comment: @Lewis, its annoying when you waste the time of people on the forum because you don't listen to the advice given in your other postings. At the time of this comment 34 people took the time to read this question. Several took the time to answer and repeat the suggestions from your previous posting. This time could be better spent helping other who really do need the help.

Answer (score 2):

Add a System.out statement in `mousePressed()` and you will see that it is always called:

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mousePressed");
        getBoard()[e.getY() / multiplier][e.getX() / multiplier] = !getBoard()[e.getY() / multiplier][e.getX() / multiplier];
        repaint();
    }
```

Like others suggested in your [other very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552392/keeping-a-mouselistener-always-running/16552941), the problem stems from your use of timers in your paint method.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            g.setColor(board[i][j] ? Color.green : Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(j * multiplier, i * multiplier, multiplier - 1, multiplier - 1);
        }
    }
    //if (isActive) {  // take this stuff out...
    //    timer.start();
    //}
    //else {
    //    timer.stop();
    //    repaint();
    //}
}
```

The `paintComponent()` method should be used to draw your components only.  Do not use it to start/stop timers, make additional calls to `repaint()`, or otherwise call any other kind of program logic.  Rethink your design, especially in `paintComponent()`.

Comment: main problem could be if (isActive) { and by testing Timer.isRunning too, to avoiding multiple instances in the same moment

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what whiskeyspider said, if you click on a cell while it's running, you won't see the  cell light up until the next generation, and only if that position is considered alive, after processing, in the next generation.